# Why are these iPads Disabled?

Tags: ios, ipad

I work at a library which uses some iPads as room signs to tell patrons if group study rooms are available.  We have three which are in the "iPad is disabled, Connect to iTunes" state.  We know how to restore the devices from this status, but are wondering how they got there.

The last time this happened, our Apple support tech said it occurred because the power was drained and the date was off which prevented activation and network access.  However this doesn't make very much sense as the iPads run a kiosk app which alerts me when it goes on and off battery power and I haven't received many such emails lately.  Some Google searching revealed improperly entering the passcode can disable an iPad as well which makes me wonder if someone deliberately did so, thus disabling the devices.  Are there any other possibilities I am missing?

Comment: Best solution is to restore one of them, attempt to break it, then figure out how to keep it from happening again. On the other hand, if you don't already use an MDM, you should consider one. The ability to control and manage the iPads will be greatly enhanced. My institution uses JAMF Pro  but the [JAMF Now](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/?v=3) platform should be just what you need because you have few devices. I also have tried Radix Viso as an MDM for Android devices, but there is a built-in Apple MDM component which I have not tried.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  There are downsides, though.  For example we can prevent patrons from using the touch screen, but then can't restart the device when their contents end up inverted (which happens occasionally).  I second the need for MDM and appreciate the recommendation.  Our college IT department doesn't use it for some reason.  However I will bring up JAMF Now as it may be the solution we need.

Comment: Through the MDM you can restart the iPad at any time, so long as it is connected to the network.